# Diablo 2 resurrected: can you turn off subtitles?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

I was playing Diablo 2 Resurrected and there are subtitles turned on by default in the game for the cinematics. I prefer to have the subtitles turned off. Can you turn off subtitles, and if so, how?

Comment: On a forum they're suggesting Options → Gameplay → Subtitles. If that's true I'll add it as an answer